# How to plot time series only with portions of dataframes that have unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

| Index | CODE | DATE | STATION | TMAX | TMIN | PP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 130 | 1/01/1991 | NaN | 32.6 | 23.4 | 0 |
| 1 | 130 | 2/01/1991 | NaN | 31.2 | 22.4 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10865 | 130 | 31/12/2020 | Rica Playa | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10866 | 182 | 1/01/1991 | NaN | 31.4 | 29.3 | 0,5 |
| 10867 | 182 | 2/01/1991 | NaN | 33.5 | 30.1 | 0.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Every STATION has a unique CODE and the DATE is since 1/01/1991 to 31/12/2020 (dd/mm/yy). I want to plot a time series of TMAX, TMIN AND PP (three variables in the same graphic) for every STATION from 1/01/1991 to  31/12/2020. There are 371 stations with unique code.

Woud you mind to help me please? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide your dataframe as code or file contents that can be copies and pasted instead of an image.

Comment: I have 371 STATIONS and each one have data from 1/01/1991 to 31/12/2020 so it's a little difficult to provide the df as code or the files. The df has a len of 4057702. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, but you can provide about 10 lines that provide a representative sample of your code.

Comment: Okay i'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [ { "Index": 0, "CODE": 130, "DATE": "1/01/1991", "STATION": np.NaN, "TMAX": "32.6", "TMIN": "23.4", "PP": "0" }, { "Index": 1, "CODE": 130, "DATE": "2/01/1991", "STATION": np.NaN, "TMAX": "31.2", "TMIN": "22.4", "PP": "0" }, { "Index": 10865, "CODE": 130, "DATE": "31/12/2020", "STATION": "Rica Playa", "TMAX": np.NaN, "TMIN": np.NaN, "PP": np.NaN }, { "Index": 10866, "CODE": 182, "DATE": "1/01/1991", "STATION": np.NaN, "TMAX": "31.4", "TMIN": "29.3", "PP": "0.5" }, { "Index": 10867, "CODE": 182, "DATE": "2/01/1991", "STATION": np.NaN, "TMAX": "33.5", "TMIN": "30.1", "PP": "0.6" } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# make sure these columns are of dtype float
df['TMAX'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['TMAX'])
df['TMIN']= pd.to_numeric(df['TMIN'])
df['PP']= pd.to_numeric(df['PP'])

# load the dates as datetime
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# groupby code
stations = df.groupby(['CODE'])
```

Now you can acces each station by station code and plot the graph for that station:

```
stations.get_group(182).plot('DATE',["TMAX", "TMIN", "PP"])
```

Output for station 182:

[image]

To loop over the groups:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name, station_df in stations:
  #create plot
  plot = station_df.plot('DATE',["TMAX", "TMIN", "PP"])
  # save to file
  plt.savefig(str(name) + '.png')
```

Comment: Thanks but when i want to loop it with    for i in stations:
    stations.get_group(i).plot('DATE',["TMAX", "TMIN", "PP"]) I got an error: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. How can i loop it to get the series of all graphics?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example to solve this.